# Update several fields in thousands rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have database MS SQL Server 2008 R2 with loading 2000 transactions per second. Tables are:

```
'lion_Tasks'(uid_obj, order_new, __usn_field_order_new, and more 40 fields)
```

and

```
'lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts'(uid_task_cp, uid_user_cp, __usn_entity_cp and more 20 fields )
```

Web-server get 10.000 objects, in which only one field has changed 'order_new'. Only 3 fields need to be updated in the database. These objects I pass in a table parameter to the stored procedure:

I tried to rewrite this stored procedure several times without any performance changes, it still trips out **10-20 seconds**, current version is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.lion_UpdateTasksNewOrder
( @Table TasksNewOrderTableType READONLY) 
WITH RECOMPILE AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ErrorCode     int
SET @ErrorCode = -1

UPDATE TasksTable
SET     
  order_new = t.ORDER_NEW,   
  __usn_field_order_new = t.USN_ORDER_NEW
FROM dbo.lion_Tasks TasksTable
INNER JOIN @Table t
ON t.UUID_TASK = TasksTable.uid_obj

  IF( @@ERROR != 0 )
  BEGIN
      SET @ErrorCode = -1
      GOTO Cleanup
  END                       

UPDATE TasksTableCP
SET 
  __usn_entity_cp = tcp.USN_ENTITY
FROM dbo.lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts TasksTableCP
INNER JOIN @Table tcp
ON tcp.UUID_TASK = TasksTableCP.uid_task_cp AND tcp.UUID_USER = TasksTableCP.uid_user_cp

  IF( @@ERROR != 0 )
  BEGIN
      SET @ErrorCode = -1
      GOTO Cleanup
  END

  RETURN 0
  Cleanup:
  RETURN @ErrorCode    
END
```

The temp-database is located on the SSD disk. Maybe someone tell me what to do for acceleration?

The estimated execution plan is:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byq2JzTwm

Table script:

```
USE [lion_data]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts]    Script Date: 09/05/2018 11:31:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts](
    [uid_obj_cp] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [uid_task_cp] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [uid_user_cp] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [_order_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uid_marker_cp] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [date_begin_cp] [datetime] NULL,
    [date_end_cp] [datetime] NULL,
    [readed_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [collapsed_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_entity_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_order_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_uid_marker_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_date_begin_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_date_end_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_readed_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_collapsed_cp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [__usn_field_list_tags_cp] [int] NULL,
    [Contacts] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [__usn_field_contacts_cp] [int] NULL,
    [uid_user_marker] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [__usn_field_uid_user_marker] [int] NULL,
    [focus_cp] [int] NULL,
    [__usn_field_focus_cp] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [uid_obj_cp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Scripts for indexes:

```
USE [lion_data]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_lion_Tasks]    Script Date: 09/05/2018 11:28:44 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[lion_Tasks] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_lion_Tasks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [uid_obj] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [lion_data]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_lion_Tasks_CP_Uid_Task]    Script Date: 09/05/2018 11:29:17 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_lion_Tasks_CP_Uid_Task] ON [dbo].[lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts] 
(
    [uid_task_cp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [lion_data]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_lion_Tasks_CP_Uid_User]    Script Date: 09/05/2018 11:29:30 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_lion_Tasks_CP_Uid_User] ON [dbo].[lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts] 
(
    [uid_user_cp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Post the execution plans please: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Are the combination of `UUID_TASK` and `UUID_USER` unique? If so, you can have a `UNIQUE` index designated on the table type and not need to copy it into a temp table first.

Comment: `10-20 seconds` - is this a db query time or overall time of the round trip starting from client-side request? What is the time of running this scenario with empty sp body (`create proc dbo.asdf @foo type as ;`)?

Comment: @GePard can you add `CREATE INDEX` scripts for clustered indexes of both tables?

Comment: Ivan, yes. Table 'Tasks' has index by field 'uid_obj', table 'Tasks_Changes_Parts' has index by field 'uid_task_cp' and index by field 'uid_user_cp'.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX` script for `CLUSTERED INDEX` please. Clustered is usually the primary key index. Right click->generate script->create index script. And could you please replace `estimated execution plan` with `actual execution plan`?

Comment: This is actual plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byq2JzTwm

Comment: OK, right click on the table `lion_Tasks_Changes_Parts` in SSMS, `Tasks->Generate script->CREATE TABLE` (not sure in menu order but it is very straightforward anyway). And please add this script to your question.

Comment: Ivan, I added script to my question.

Comment: `10.000 objects` vs `Actual Number of Rows 1` ?

Comment: Sorry, Ivan. But how to get it on the production server? There are 2 thousand transactions per second going on. How to get the right line from a ton of lines in the profiler?